# How to tune weights in Voting Classifier (Sklearn)

Tags: scikit-learn, model-selection, ensemble-modeling, parameter-estimation

I am trying to do the following:

```py
 vc = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('gbc', GradientBoostingClassifier()),
                                   ('rf', RandomForestClassifier()), 
                                   ('svc', SVC(probability=True))],
                       voting='soft',
                       n_jobs=-1,
                       weights=[2, 3, 1])
cross_val_score(vc, X_new, y, n_jobs=-1)
```

In this, I want to tune the parameter `weights`. If I use `GridSearchCV`, it is taking a lot of time. Since it needs to fit the model for each iteration. Which is not required, I guess. Better would be use something like `prefit` used in `SelectModelFrom` function from `sklearn.model_selection`.

Is there any other option or I am misinterpreting something?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Have a look on this [link](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_ensemble_classifier.html). It describes very well how to tune weights in voting classifier with classic for loops.
Hope it helps :)